# Ordering / Sorting Mechanism

Tags: jquery

I'm in need of a mechanism to allow a user to control the order of a number of items in a list. I was curious if anyone had any recommendations as far as jQuery plugins for a list of items that can be both selected and dragged and dropped to reorder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) works great for me.

Comment: Well *derp*. Didn't see that one. Oh well. Points for you sir!